After setting up Ubuntu Pro, Extended Security Maintenance is showing as active until 31/12/99
After setting up Ubuntu Pro, Extended Security Maintenance is showing as active until 31/12/99 in Software and Updates. I have this on 2 machines. I assume it's just a cosmetic problem.


why? you want it to show 12/31/99? :+

Is it 1999 or 2099? That seems to be the question

Yes, it'd be great to have support until 2099 but I think even that is beyond the lengthy LTS Ubuntu provides!

What does the pro security-status command say?

Thanks:1751 packages installed:
1662 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
88 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
1 package from a third party
To get more information about the packages, run
pro security-status --help
for a list of available options.

This machine is attached to an Ubuntu Pro subscription.
Main/Restricted packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled until 2034.
Universe/Multiverse packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled until 2034. You have received 8 security
updates.

I think the Ubuntu Pro tab shows the end-of-support date correctly.

Thanks - it does, I just wanted to highlight this cosmetic bug.
